# How to open SharePoint application page in modal dialog (popup) using c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Some times there is requirement to open a SharePoint application page as a popup. So how can a SP application page be opened as a popup using C# ?

Comment: Suggestion: You might just simply handle that on the client side through JavaScript instead of C# by using window.open(..) [http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml]

Answer (score 0):

**C# Code:**

```
void OpenApplicationPageAsPopup(){
string strWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
string strPageURL = strWebUrl + "/_layouts/MyLayoutFolder/MyPage.aspx";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), ClientID, "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(openModelDialogPopup('" + strPageURL + "'), \"SP.js\");", true);

}
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function openModelDialogPopup(strPageURL ) {

    var dialogOptions = {
        title: "This is Modal Dialog", //Popup title.
        url: strPageURL, 
        width: 600, // Width of the dialog.
        height: 400
    };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', dialogOptions);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me when trying to open a page (not a New/Edit/DispView): `An exception occurred while rendering the Ribbon on the SharePoint Page. The following exception was thrown : System.ArgumentException: The Ribbon Tab with id: "Ribbon.Read" has not been made available for this page or does not exist. Use Ribbon.MakeTabAvailable().`